# SimpleDateFormat can not parse string to Date

Tags: java

I'm so ashamed asking this question, but I have no other choice.

I want to convert this string to date:

```
 2015-11-25T19:36:39.571+06:00
```

To convert it I use SImpleDateFormat:

```
String str = "2015-11-25T19:36:39.571+06:00";       

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

Date date = format.parse(str);

System.out.println(date);
```

When I launch this code it gives to me `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:` exception.

I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (In java 7)

```
    String str = "2015-11-25T19:36:39.571+06:00";       

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    Date date = format.parse(str);

    System.out.println(date);
```

**XXX** is available in Java 7 as Timezone offset, see the Javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because of wrong pattern used.Z isInstead of **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ** use pattern **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX**

Z represents Time zone in **RFC 822 time zone format** i.e., like this -0800

So, your code will look like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
```

Comment: X is available from Java 7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not correspond entirely to the input string, you have a slight type in the time zone part of your format.

Change your format in the following way to make it work:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Or change your input string to:

```
String str = "2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Below Pattern it works fine

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your input String according to the pattern you have used.
remove the last ':' from the str variable.
change:

```
    String str = "2015-11-25T19:36:39.571+06:00";
```

in to:

```
    String str = "2015-11-25T19:36:39.571+0600";
```

and run. It'll work.
Here is the fiddle:
[working link](https://ideone.com/GZxFS9)